# How can I send error output to both stdout and file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

If I use this

```
cmd 2>/var/error.log
```

Then my error goes to that file but then I can't see on screen.

Is there any way I can simultaneously show it on screen as well as send to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display both stdout and stderr on the terminal while *only* sending stderr to `err.log`:

```
cmd 2> >(tee err.log >&2)
```

`>(...)` is *process substitution*.  (The space between the two consecutive `>` is essential.)  This sends stderr and only stderr to the `tee` command.

The `>&2` causes the error messages remain in stderr.  This would be important, for example, if this line occurs inside some script whose stdin or stderr is being redirected.  (Hat tip: Chepner.)

Comment: @user3214546 The error output may sometimes, depending on timing, show up late, after the system has written a new prompt.  But, if you hit enter, you will see that the system does not attempt to execute the error output.  This is because the error output, however it appears, is __not__ really on the command line.    You can enter a new command as usual, say `ls`, and execute it with no interference from the late output.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you might want to use `>(tee err.log >&2)` so that the error messages go back to standard error, rather than standard output. It only makes a difference if the line occurs inside another script which might be redirecting *its* standard error elsewhere, though.

Comment: @chepner Nice improvement!  Answer updated to maintain stderr as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd 2>&1 | tee /tmp/error.log
```

Comment: But that will send stdout as well in that file , is there any way just to send error output in file